# Indirect UNIQUE constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've had a following set of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE sellers (
    id       integer PRIMARY KEY,
    ....
);

CREATE TABLE buyers (
    id       integer PRIMARY KEY,
    ....
);

CREATE TABLE invoices (
    id        integer PRIMARY KEY,
    number    varchar(40),
    buyer_id  integer REFERENCES buyers(id),
    seller_id integer REFERENCES sellers(id),
    UNIQUE(seller_id, number),
    ....
);
```

The UNIQUE constraint is enforces the constraint that one seller can have only one invoice with given number.

I wanted to create a new table, mostly as a many-to-many relationship between `buyers` and `sellers`:

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers (
    id        integer PRIMARY KEY,
    buyer_id  integer REFERENCES buyers(id),
    seller_id integer REFERENCES sellers(id),
    ....
);
```

As a normalization effort, i would like to change `invoices` to refer to `suppliers`, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
    id        integer PRIMARY KEY,
    number    varchar(40),
    supplier_id  integer REFERENCES suppliers(id),
    ....
);
```

My question is: how can I replace the UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: what does this constraint represent, at the business level? What is the `Number` field?

Comment: Number is like Invoice No. - issuer of invoices gives unique number to each invoice they issue (and it is usually not an actual number as in sequence of digits :) )

Comment: Are you sure you want the constraint to be `UNIQUE (buyer_id, number)` and not `UNIQUE (seller_id, buyer_id, number)` ?

Comment: Oops... Actually I want `UNIQUE (seller_id, number)` :). Thanks for pointing that out, corrected it.

Comment: Yes, `(seller_id, number)` makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a composite primary key for `suppliers`:

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers (
    buyer_id  integer REFERENCES buyers(id),
    seller_id integer REFERENCES sellers(id),
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (buyer_id, seller_id),
    ...
);
```

and keep your `invoices` table intact, only changing the two foreign keys into one:

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
    id        integer PRIMARY KEY,
    number    varchar(40),
    buyer_id  integer,
    seller_id integer,
    UNIQUE (seller_id, number),
    FOREIGN KEY (buyer_id, seller_id)
      REFERENCES suppliers (buyer_id, seller_id),
    ....
);
```

I guess that this design will be useful, if you plan to have more columns in the `suppliers` table that are related to the `seller - buyer` relationship. Otherwise, you could have a view that gathers data from the `invoices` table:

```
CREATE VIEW suppliers AS
SELECT DISTINCT buyer_id, seller_id
FROM invoices ;
```